# getting second value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

this one should be pretty easy, but I can't seem to figure it out. Here is my ARRAY:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ClientId] => 47063
            [CampaignId] => 2169
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ClientId] => 49786
            [CampaignId] => 2169
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ClientId] => 47063
            [CampaignId] => 2168
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ClientId] => 49786
            [CampaignId] => 2168
        )

)
```

I am looping through this array  trying to get the values of "CampaignID" and "ClientId" separately. For example, for [0] I  need to get 47063 and 2169. Unfortunatly, when I try to ECHO these values, I get all of them  in a string, 470632169497862169470632168497862168. Basically, each "Client_Id" and "Campaign_Id" are going to be included in a SQL query. Here is the code:

($array is the array)

```php
foreach($array as $key => $client){
    
    foreach($client as $key => $client2){
        
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE CampaignId = '".$client2."' AND ClientId = '".$client2."' ";


  }
}
```

The entire SQL query isn't there, nor is the code to return the data, bt that is besides the point. Basically, I need to get "Campaign_Id" into the first where clause and "Client_Id" into the second.

I have tried so far:

```php
 1. $client2[0]
 2. $client2[1]
 3. $client2['CampaignId']
 4. $client2['ClientId']
```

All I seem to be getting is numbers from the values, instead of the entire value. What can I do to get my values, to put into my SQL string?

Comment: Of course you get them all in a row, if you just echo one after the other, and don't put any separator between them ... does that actually surprise you?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
echo $client2[0]['CampaignId'] ." and ". $client2[0]['ClientId'];
```

For your MySqL query you could do something like:

```
foreach($array as $cl){
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE CampaignId = '".$cl['CampaignId']."' AND ClientId = '".$cl['ClientId']."' ";
}
```

Except, you **should never run this snippet** in anything close to a production version as it is **wide open to SQL-injection**.

Instead, maybe something like this will work:

```
/* connect to database */
$DBlink = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
/* create a prepared statement */
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($DBlink, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE CampaignId = ? AND ClientId = ?");

foreach($array as $cl){
 /* bind parameters for markers */
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $cl['CampaignId'], $cl['ClientId']);
 /* execute query */
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

 $result = $stmt->get_result();
 while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   // do something with results in $myrow ...
 }
}
```